# Components containing public dialog: MatDialog, in constructor fails to load

Tags: angular, angular6

After upgrading from Angular 5.2 to 6 
The app fails to load components components containing public dialog: MatDialog in the constructor.

building/serving using --prod flag. (Works fine using ng serve and ng build.)

Console error when using --aot:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: factory is not a function
```

package.json

```
"@angular/animations": "6.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "6.0.1",
"@angular/common": "6.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
"@angular/core": "6.0.0",
"@angular/flex-layout": "6.0.0-beta.15",
"@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
"@angular/http": "6.0.0",
"@angular/material": "6.0.1",
++
```

Update, the problem exists in all components where we "inject" a angular service.

```
 constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { } 
 constructor(private bottomSheet: MatBottomSheet) { }
```

Comment: you need to specify your component with the dialog as `entryComponents` in NgModule

Comment: All the dialog components are added to the `entryComponents` in the appModule.
when I add `public dialog: MatDialog` to a constructor in any component it will fail to load, also in a empty component only containing the constructor and no "dialog code".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50290571/components-containing-public-dialog-matdialog-in-constructor-fails-to-load how did u solve this issue,i have the same issue